# How to route to two pages on certain conditions with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(" ") in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have a strange requirement. Since I have a 404 page on my angularjs app, I don't want to leave it unnoticed because it has a random joke API added to it.

Now my angular js application uses UI route provider for routing. I have a

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home")
```

code in my angularjs configuration. I want the page to redirect to home if there isn't any path specified. E.g. https://mypage.com should route to https://mypage.com/#!/home but if someone types a wrong state name manually, it should redirect it to the 404 page.

My only question is since this requires two routings in otherwise statement, is it even possible? And if it is possible, then how?

Comment: have you tried this $urlRouterProvider.when("/", "/home"), it would route to /home seeing / or nothing in URL.

Comment: No this is a new one for me. But how do I route anything else typed in the browser address bar to a 404 page? Are you suggesting combining this and otherwise?